# GATLING Rest API testing - java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null

Tags: java, rest, performance-testing, load-testing, gatling

I am trying to do performance testing for a REST API, I am using below code:

```
val httpConf = http.   baseUrl("http://localhost:8080")  
    .header("Accept","application/json")  
    .header("content-type","application/json") //scenario 
val scn = scenario("get user")
    .exec(http("get user request")
    .get("/endpoint")
    .check(status is 200)) 
setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1)))
    .protocols(httpConf)
```

but I am receiving this error:

```
DEBUG io.gatling.http.client.impl.DefaultHttpClient - Failed to connect to remoteAddress=gatling.io/34.77.242.251:443 from localAddress=null
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
```

I tried adding Proxy as well  `.proxy(Proxy("localhost", 8080))` but after adding proxy I am seeing below error

```
Caused by: io.netty.handler.proxy.HttpProxyHandler$HttpProxyConnectException: http, none, localhost/127.0.0.1:8080 => gatling.io/<unresolved>:443, status: 400**
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an ERROR, it's a DEBUG log. You can just ignore this. Also, you really shouldn't enable DEBUG logging when running load tests or you will destroy performance.

This DEBUG log happens when Gatling can't perform the warm up request, typically because you're behind a enterprise proxy.
Please check the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_protocol/#automatic-warm-up).

Comment: I think that's an issue because when I am running the test the load test is failing. I am trying this in Mac but when I am following same steps in my personal computer which is windows everything is working fine

Comment: No. This is a DEBUG log and can't possibly cause your test to fail. If your test doesn't work, it's for a different reason. Please provide proper information, such as full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load test your local application which lives at `http://localhost:8080` using [Gatling Frontline](https://gatling.io/gatling-frontline/) - you need to be able to reach the Frontline servers and if you're behind the [corporate proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) - you need to [specify these proxy details](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_protocol/?highlight=proxy#proxy-parameters). But make sure to specify your corporate proxy host and port, not application under test host and port.

If you don't intend to use Gatling Frontline - download [Gatling Open Source](https://gatling.io/open-source/), it shouldn't require to access any remote hosts. See [How to Run a Simple Load Test with Gatling](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-run-a-simple-load-test-with-gatling) article for more details if needed.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I tried with Gatling Open Source only, but I am still seeing this error.